# Image Field Browser Option

Tags: 7, entities, media

Is there any way to alter the default Drupal 7 image fields to allow a browse server option along with the default upload file option? Kind of like *imce* or *ckfinder* but for image fields instead of content (text) fields.

It seems like this could be pretty useful and I don't really see any modules that offer this kind of functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [FileField Sources](http://drupal.org/project/filefield_sources) module.  To browse the server it looks like you need to use this with [IMCE](http://drupal.org/project/imce).  From the FileField Sources project page:

> The FileField Sources module expands on this ability by allowing you
>   to select new or existing files through additional means, including:
>
> - Re-use files by an auto-complete textfield
> - Attach server-side files uploaded via FTP
> - Transfer files from a remote server (cURL required)
> - Select existing files through the IMCE file browser

Comment: That looks perfect.  I'll test it out now.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Laxman answer is correct for file fields, but as per this topic, [FileField Sources is not working](https://www.drupal.org/project/filefield_sources/issues/1177050) with drupal default image field(as per jan 2 2018).
For default drupal 7 image field, you should use [IMCE for FileField](https://www.drupal.org/project/imce_filefield) instead: after installed the module, go to configuration page of your image field, and check "Allow users to select files from IMCE File Browser for this field" checkbox.