# How to browse the server to upload files from there in Drupal 7

Tags: files

I need to upload the audios and videos on server in a specific folder via FTP and then let the content managers to select them when they want to upload any of them in `add/content` path (because it takes a long time to upload them via the Add Content user interface). Is there such a capability in Drupal 7?

Comment: @FelixEve did you see the `Image` word in my question? I'm talking about videos and audios

Comment: Still just browsing the server for files. IMCE does all of that. File type is irrelevant.

Comment: @Drupalist file is a file. Do you really think file browser will care what's inside the file?

Comment: Related: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/76823/16495 http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/76525/16495

Answer (score 2, accepted):

****UPDATE****

Best option is to use https://drupal.org/project/imce_filefield
This is specially made to upload files to sites/default/files and add them.

Just configure imce and the field.

Uninstall file field sources, because it's not compatible to have them at the same time

---

*Old anwser*

You could use the FileField Sources module. To browse the server it looks like you need to use this with IMCE. From the FileField Sources project page:

```
The FileField Sources module expands on this ability by allowing you to 
select new or existing files through additional means, including:

    Re-use files by an auto-complete textfield
    Attach server-side files uploaded via FTP
    Transfer files from a remote server (cURL required)
    Select existing files through the IMCE file browser
```

This question / answer was on another question:
[Image Field Browser Option](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15191/image-field-browser-option)

Comment: Does this work for video and audio?

Comment: I had to upload the file by imce, to get it seen, but there are some patches which can allow file field source + imce to see all file even if not uploaded with imce.
I noticed some patches but patches aint so nice. *EDITED ANSWER*